# Error in insert the value into database in asp.net ,c# of registration form

Tags: asp.net, c#-4.0

Code show as follow:

```
nection cnn = new SqlConnection("Data Source=USER-PC\\KHEMCHAND;Integrated Security=True");

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    cnn.Open();
}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{  
    SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_ragistration values(@f_name,@l_name,@email_id,@pass_word,@[date of brth],@add_ress,@gender)", cnn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", Texfname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_name", Texlname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email_id", Texemail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass_word", Texpwd.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[date o birth]", Texdbt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add_ress", Texadd.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", DropDownList1.Text);
    cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    cnn.Close();
}
```

Comment: **WHAT** is the error?? Please post the complete and exact error message....

Answer (score 1):

Change  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[date o birth]", Texdbt.Text);`  to  `cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[date of birth]", Texdbt.Text);` in Insert parameters value assigning.  And also dont open the connection in the page load event.  Befor executing the query open the connection, Execute the query and then close the connection for a better approach

```
       cnn.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
       cnn.Close();
```

Answer (score 1):

You can try with below way, I hope this is good approach (though database execution should put in Data Access Layer), thanks for your time.

```
public string ConnectionString 
{
    get
    {
        return "Data Source=USER-PC\\KHEMCHAND;Integrated Security=True";
    }
}

protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

}

protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand(
            "insert into tbl_ragistration values(@f_name,@l_name,@email_id,@pass_word,@[date of brth],@add_ress,@gender)"
            ,cnn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", Texfname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_name", Texlname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email_id", Texemail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass_word", Texpwd.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[date o birth]", Texdbt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add_ress", Texadd.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", DropDownList1.Text);
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

make sure you declare also the column names on your insert statement:

```
protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    using (SqlConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(ConnectionString))
    {
        using (SqlCommand cmd =new SqlCommand(
            "insert into tbl_ragistration (f_name,l_name,email_id,pass_word,[date of brth],add_ress,gender) values (@f_name,@l_name,@email_id,@pass_word,@dateofbrth,@add_ress,@gender)"
            ,cnn))
        {
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", Texfname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_name", Texlname.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email_id", Texemail.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass_word", Texpwd.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@dateofbirth", Texdbt.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add_ress", Texadd.Text);
            cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", DropDownList1.Text);
            cnn.Open();
            cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
        }
    }
}
```

Regards

Answer (score 0):

> 1. Open the connection while executing the command & not on page Load & wrap your code inside a try catch block to log the error.

```
    protected void Button1_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {  
SQLConnection cnn = new SqlConnection(WebConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["yourConnectionString"].ConnectionString);

 SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("insert into tbl_ragistration values(@f_name,@l_name,@email_id,@pass_word,@[date of brth],@add_ress,@gender)", cnn);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@f_name", Texfname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@l_name", Texlname.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@email_id", Texemail.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@pass_word", Texpwd.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@[date o birth]", Texdbt.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@add_ress", Texadd.Text);
    cmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@gender", DropDownList1.Text);
    try
    {
       cnn.Open();
       cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
    catch(SQLException ex)
    {  // Log your error
       lblStatus.Text="An error occured"+ ex.Message; 
       throw ex;
    }
    finally
    {
      if(cnn!=null)
      {
          cnn.Close();
      }
    }
}
```